# Does Linux 3.10 CFS have "timeslices"?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

### Does Linux 3.10 CFS have "timeslices"?

I am confused, because [sched-design-CFS.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt) clearly states:

> CFS uses nanosecond granularity accounting and does not rely on any jiffies or
>   other HZ detail.  Thus the CFS scheduler has no notion of "timeslices" in the
>   way the previous scheduler had, and has no heuristics whatsoever.  There is
>   only one central tunable (you have to switch on CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG):
>
> /proc/sys/kernel/sched_min_granularity_ns
>
> which can be used to tune the scheduler from "desktop" (i.e., low latencies) to
>   "server" (i.e., good batching) workloads.

But then multiple task scheduler tuning guides suggest two different formulas of calculating a "timeslice". (Depending on the number of runnable tasks.) For example this [OpenSUSE guide](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/tuning/html/book.sle.tuning/cha.tuning.taskscheduler.html#sec.tuning.taskscheduler.cfs.tuning).

I am running only SCHED_FIFO threads on isolated CPUs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CFS` doesn't have timeslices "in the way the previous scheduler had".

In `CFS` a timeslice is basically the duration between consecutive switches to grant CPU execution time to the same thread. This gives you two options:

- All of your threads have enough time to execute for at least `min_granularity_ns` within one `latency_ns`. Then, your `timeslice = scheduling period * (task's weight/total weight of tasks in the run queue)`
- There are too many threads to fit in the `latency_ns`, so your timeslices get bigger to accommodate more threads that want to run according to `timeslice = number_of_running_tasks * sched_min_granularity_ns`

This is why `CFS` stands for a *Completely* Fair Scheduler, as is doesn't exclude threads with lower priorities but rather indiscriminately extends the timeslices for everyone.

Comment: aha, excellent! Thank you. So seems that I only had trouble understanding the "doesn't have timeslices **in the way the previous scheduler had**". :) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: mind accepting the answer, then? ;) @VäinöErtanen

Comment: What about cgroups' CPU shares? How it affects the timeslice?